# Add a WSD print via group policy

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, printer

I have a new wsd capable printer. Users can just discover it on the local network and add it and it works great.

How can I push this out to these users with a GPO- so they don't have to discover the printer and add it themselves? I don't want to have to configure a Windows print server, I just want to have clients automatically discover the printer and add it.

I created a user preferences item like this:
[image]

I get this error on my workstation when the gpo is applied:

```
The user 'http://10.1.1.123:80/WebServices/Device' preference item in the 'printers_gpo {guid}' Group Policy Object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070709 The printer name is invalid.' This error was suppressed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the URL to the printers built in webserver, which isn't a valid path. The GPP is expecting a UNC path.

Comment: So is there any way to add a WSD printer directly via group policy (if I can't do it this way)? I could of course setup the printer on a Windows print server, but I'd prefer to have them connect to the WSD service of the printer directly.

Comment: My hunch is that you can't do this with Group Policy without using a UNC path, which would necessitate setting up a print server. Perhaps someone else will chime in on your question with more info.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I figured as much, but wanted to check. I want to avoid adding another role to a server for this as its only a few people and I have no need for any of the features of a windows printer server.